# How do I know that the Web service architecture is based on RESTful or SOAP?

Tags: web-services

I have been working on different projects and they use different web services architecture. As a tester how can I know is the architecture based on RESTful or SOAP?

Is there any differences in the request/response behaviour?

Comment: Take a look at the differences between SOAP and REST here: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/tip/REST-vs-SOAP-How-to-choose-the-best-Web-service
Rest can be see by the URL requested as all parameters are passed and is said stateless. It also uses the GET,PUT,DELETE,POST to specify the action. You should be able to see a trace of these calls to a webservices if calls happens on your workstation/device.

Comment: As a tester, why do you _care_?

Comment: SOAP requests are always POST with an XML request body, and an XML response body. The XML will look a bit like http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383490

Comment: Thanks David & Francis for your replies. In my present job, the WebServices is based on the Restful architecture. However, when I a request is made using GET or any other command, I get a detailed XML response. So based on your replies, in the SOAP architecture, the response is XML based. Please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

A Rest API is a simple url which can be requested from a browser also while SOAP request is a more complex request with an XML structure.